# ReactJS, A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type number to be controlled

Tags: reactjs

This is the warning that I get:

```
index.js:1446 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type number to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

in input (created by InputBase)
in div (created by InputBase)
in InputBase (created by Context.Consumer)
in WithFormControlContext(InputBase) (created by WithStyles(WithFormControlContext(InputBase)))
in WithStyles(WithFormControlContext(InputBase)) (created by Input)
in Input (created by WithStyles(Input))
in WithStyles(Input) (at register-operating-instructions-sscc.js:424)
in div (created by Grid)
in Grid (created by WithStyles(Grid))
in WithStyles(Grid) (at register-operating-instructions-sscc.js:423)
in div (created by Grid)
in Grid (created by WithStyles(Grid))
in WithStyles(Grid) (at register-operating-instructions-sscc.js:1071)
in div (created by Grid)
in Grid (created by WithStyles(Grid))
in WithStyles(Grid) (at register-operating-instructions-sscc.js:1070)
in div (created by Grid)
in Grid (created by WithStyles(Grid))
in WithStyles(Grid) (at register-operating-instructions-sscc.js:1011)
in div (at register-operating-instructions-sscc.js:1010)
in RegisterOperatingInstructionsSscc (created by WithStyles(RegisterOperatingInstructionsSscc))
```

So this is the code at line 423:

```
<Grid item xs={2} style={{marginLeft: '-25px', marginRight: '55px'}}>
    <Input id="sscc-ctfm" aria-describedby="component-error-text" onChange={this.handleMwAsignadoCtfm} value={valueMwAsignado} disableUnderline type="number"/>
</Grid>
```

`this.handleMwAsignadoCtfm` is:

```
handleMwAsignadoCtfm = (e) => {
    const {scSelected, row, existeData} = this.state;
    const key = 'mw_assigned';
    const value = e.target.value
    this.props.getSscc(key, value, scSelected, row, existeData);
    this.setState({valueMwAsignado: value});
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What's the initial value of `valueMwAsignado` ? Setting `value={valueMwAsignado || ''}` should get rid of the warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that the initial value of `valueMwAsignado` is an empty string. Otherwise the initial value will be `undefined`, which means no value is provided and the component in uncontrolled.

As soon as you type something, update the `valueMwAsignado` variable and pass it as the value, the value is now provided and the component became controlled.

Comment: Thanks, now in my constructor I have: `constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            valueMwAsignado: ''"} etc...`